# Problemas con Sentencia MySQL PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Tengo un proyecto de en PHP que en mi PC funciona todo correctamente pero cuando subo el proyecto a https://www.000webhost.com/ la sentencia no funciona, en mi PC utilice un `Print_r($row1)` para ver y me devuelve los datos normal pero en el webhost lo único que me devuelve es esto `Array()` y en el host la conexion a la base de datos esta correcta.

Este es parte de mi codigo:

Conexion

```
<?php

    $link = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id*****_todolistdb';
    $usuario = 'id******';
    $pass = '********';

    try{
        $conexionPDO = new PDO($link, $usuario, $pass);    
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print "Error : " . $e->getmessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Consulta

```
<php?
           $resultado = $conexionPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM todoTable WHERE completado = 0");
           $resultado->execute();
           $row1 = $resultado->fetchAll();
           print_r($row1);

           foreach($row1 as $row): 
         ?>
                        HTLM Code
     <?php
            endforeach

            ?>
```

[image: Servidor WebHost]

[image: Local con XAMPP]

Comment: Tu proyecto está alojado en webhost?, y tu base de datos dónde está alojada?

Comment: En el administrador de base de datos de web host la conexión esta bien lo que no se me ejecuta es la consulta

Comment: Por lo pronto tienes un error aquí abriendo el bloque de código PHP: `<php?` , lo correcto sería esto: **`<?php`**

Comment: En el código esta bien fue ahí que me equivoque cuando estaba formulando la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

La lo solucione era que tenia un "Problema" en la sentencia

Lo tenia asi

```
$resultado = $conexionPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM todoTable WHERE completado = 0");
```

Lo cambie asi

```
$resultado = $conexionPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM todotable WHERE completado = 0");
```

en la local no tenia problema con la letra mayúscula pero cuando lo subía al localhost del web hosting ahí si tenia problema con la letra mayúscula.

Comment: El "problema" es que en Windows la BD se instala por defecto con nombres de tabla insensible a mayúsculas, a diferencia de sistemas basados en Unix. Se puede cambiar, pero en muchos hostings el usuario no lo puede hacer, por lo que se recomienda mantengas siempre el nombre de las tablas para que sea mas portatil entre plataformas. [Más Información](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias por el consejo.